# How can I find out what included code makes my iOS universal binary so large?

Tags: objective-c, ios, optimization, size

I have a large iOS app for iPhone and iPad. I have optimised the images and reduced all associated data to a minimum which has made a reasonable difference but now my app is 50% "Application Binary" - the single file that contains all of my code.

How can I find out what makes it so large and attempt to start thinning out possibly unnecessary files or dependencies?

Comment: what is the total size you are getting? , I would say that any app without graphics or code will be around 1mb to start with, but i assume you are talking about something much bigger in size...

Comment: The compiled code is over 5MB which seems excessive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the project file in Xcode. At the bottom of the Summary tab, under the Linked frameworks and libraries you can see against which libraries you are linking. Frameworks are ok, you are linking against them dynamically as their binary already sits on the phone. But you might find here also static libraries (with extension .a) that are "copied" to the bundle of your application. This is called static linking. So they will make your bundle more fat. On the Build Phases tab you can see which source files you are compiling and thus linking in your binary, these make the other part of the compiled program code. The rest of the bundle are resources, images, etc. but I guess this you checked already.